# recursive function returning only the valid entry

Tags: python

A function that returns only a valid entry.

Code:

```
def test():
    x = input('1' or '0')
    if x == '1'
        x = 'yes'
    elif x == '0'
        x = 'no'
    else:
        print('Error!')
        test()
    return x

x = test()
print(x)
```

How can I ensure returning of x only returns a valid entry (1 or 0)?

At the moment if I enter a number other then 1 or 0, test function calls itself and this will be the value returned regardless of whatever input in enter after this point...

Why does this happen and how can I correct this so it returns only 1 which will be 'yes' or '0' which will be 'no' to the function caller?

cheers

Comment: There should have been some syntax errors, and the line `x = input('1' or '0')` is silly, though syntactically correct...

Answer (score 3):

You are not storing the result of the recursive call anywhere. You need to change:

```
else:
    print('Error!')
    test()
return x
```

to:

```
else:
    print('Error!')
    x = test()
return x
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be much more straightforwardly written using a loop, and as a bonus won't fail if the user makes more than 1000 mistakes, but since you're asking: your recursive call to `test()` is throwing away the return value of the recursive call. You should do `x = test()`.